# Graphql mutations with json

Tags: graphql, plugin-craftql

Can someone confirm for me that the current status of craftql (Craft 3.7) does not allow mutations that can save JSON content to entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL Mutations are indeed supported in Craft 3.7: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#mutations

Comment: Thx Ben.
Yes but can you save a json string/object to a field in the syntax? I didn't think you could

Comment: You can save any string, so provided you JSON encode your object first, it should work.

Comment: It does! Thank you. I thought JSON wasn't supported but i think the JSON field/type isnt supported in mysql or as part of the Graph schema but encoded string works